# Generating multivariate random variable with normal and exponential marginals

Tags: multivariate-analysis, random-generation, exponential-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, numpy

I have a collection of data points of the form $[U, V, X, Y]$, where $U$ ~ $N(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$; $V$ ~ $N(\mu_2, \sigma_2)$; $X$ ~ $exp(\lambda_1)$; and $Y$ ~ $exp(\lambda_2)$, and I am looking to generate fictional data points of the form [u, v, x, y]. These 4 data points are all interrelated, so generating them independently is not a realistic option. I've attempted to approximate $X$ and $Y$ by normal distributions, which reduces the problem to generating from a multivariate normal distribution, and this is easily done with `numpy.random.multivariate_normal`, based on the observed mean vector and covariance matrix. The results of this approximation are ok, but the results for the $X$ and $Y$ columns could be better. Is there a way to generate these variables, while being able to maintain the underlying distributions of these variables and account for the variables not being independent?

Comment: Check out copulas

Comment: There's an infinity of ways for two variables to be dependent. Can you explain more about what properties you want?

Comment: What is the source for the correlarions of $U,V,X,Y$? The same source could probably provide the correlations of $U,V,\ln X,\ln Y$ instead, and then those four variables could be modeled normally.

Comment: the log of an exponential is fairly left skew; I don't think you can just model it as normal (maybe that's okay for some applications but it would be problematic for others)

Comment: @pistol-pete Here's a sample from a Gaussian copula with  Gaussian (x) and and Exponential (y) margins https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoVAY.png ... is that sufficient? If you just need a specific correlation you can get there  approximately (e.g. via Taylor expansion) and then tweak it.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks, I'll give it a try, and see if the results are sufficient.